# Identify this unknown car from picture

Tags: identify-this

Can someone help me to identify this car. I suspect it is a Toyota, and it was bought in Austria (second hand) around 1995.

[image: Toyota]

Comment: I don't know how Austrian numberplates work, but in the UK one can determine the ages of the car from its numberplate. This is obvious with the places like "08", but it also works for the older ones. Knowing the age could help in identifying the model

Comment: this Austrian number plate only reveals the district (KO for Korneuburg in Lower Austria), but there is no information about the age except the time when the black-on-white plates replaced the older white-on-black plates: that was in 1988. this only tells us that there must have been a (re-)registration after that year, but not whether the car itself predates that period.

Comment: This is a fourth generation BD Mazda 323. Point of interest is they do excellent handbrake skids.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Mazda 323 (aka Familia or GLC), circa 1980-85.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Familia#/media/File:1981-1982_Mazda_323_(BD)_Deluxe_sedan_(8302481590).jpg

Comment: The chrome over the light does not match the corolla proposed in the other answer but it clearly match the mazda. check this picture (look at the taillight and the chrome over them) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Familia#/media/File:1983_Mazda_323_(BD_Series_2)_Deluxe_sedan_(2013-05-11).jpg

Comment: @Rémi - I'm sorry, but the Mazda 323 pictured in this answer is spot on. Definitely what it is, regardless of the chrome, the a/b/c-pillar angles are correct, the rubber trim matches, the trunk lid markings and key hole ... even the rims are an exact match.

Comment: @PAULSTER yes this is what I wrote in my comments, I simply linked to the same car from another angle

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an 80's Toyota Corolla to me, probably the [AE82](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_Corolla_(E80)#Europe) model.

Comment: I disagree. Look carefully at the base of the black trim behind the rear door on the Toyota. The Toyota's trim decreases in width at the bottom. On the Mazda GLC, the same aft-of-the-window trim piece has a consistent width all the way down to the window sill.

Comment: 1000% not an AE82 rolla. It's a 323.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Mazda_GLC_1983]

Looks like a Mazda GLC. I just looked it up based on the other descriptions @remi @paulster said. The pictured car is probably the American version due to the extra giant bumpers.